# How to copy files from one folder to another that has different hierarchy?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, file-transfer

I have many files that are stored in a deep hierarchy like this:

```
F:\Files\FX\Water\APX\Build\Setup\myfile.mp4
F:\Files\FX\1\2\3\4\otherfile.mp4
```

and I want to copy them into another drive that has one more nested layer
but at the lower folder level:

```
F:\Files\FX\Water\MICROSOFT\APX\Build\Setup\myfile.mp4
F:\Files\FX\1\MICROSOFT\2\3\4\otherfile.mp4
```

So as you can see, I am not able to do a simple copy paste. Is there a command I can run on cmd or PowerShell that will let me copy all the files at once, overriding the target files?

I am on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: I've offered a solution that should work based on the info you provided. Awaiting feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> So as you can see, I am not able to do a simple copy paste. Is there a command I can run on cmd or powershell or even an app that will let me copy all the files at once, overriding the target files?

Perhaps I am not fully understanding your question, but you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
robocopy F:\Files\FX\Water\APX\Build\Setup F:\Files\FX\Water\MICROSOFT\APX\Build\Setup *.*
```

The destination directory doesn't need to exist. [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) should be available on Windows Vista or later and has options to copy subdirectories (as needed).

Comment: `*.*` is redundant as it is the default behaviour in Robocopy, so including it won't do anything.

Comment: Understood. In this case, I intended `*.*` to show where files might go (rather than e.g `C:\some\path\*.*`). Probably should have been clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot but is there a way to use wildcards for Water, APX and Build as they change in the source and target the same way. So I need them to be * in the source and the target.

Comment: @Radiation4TheNation `RoboCopy` does support wildcards, but I'm not sure if it does for directories in a path.  If it doesn't, a simple cmd script would likely work, else this would work for everything but the `Water` directory: `robocopy F:\Files\FX\Water\ F:\Files\FX\Water\MICROSOFT /e`.  I would also recommend the following parameters: `/Log:%UserProfile%\RoboCopy.log` || `/Log+:%UserProfile%\RoboCopy.log` _(the `+` appends, whereas w/o it, the log will be overwritten upon a new execution... if running within a PS terminal, append `cmd /c` in front of command)_.

Comment: Offhand, I don't believe `robocopy` supports wildcards for folders (could be wrong, though). But to JW0914's comment, some simple scripting is the solution I would be leaning towards.

Comment: To explain it simpler I need this: copy F:/Files/FX/*/*/*/*/*.mp4  F:/Files/FX/*/MICROSOFT/*/*/*/*.mp4

Comment: Robocopy only supports wildcards when they are used in a file name. You'd need a different scripting solution for this that allows wildcards to be used in the source path.

Comment: which language i have to use for this? i thought there would be a regex like solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using Robocopy.

1. Open a Command Prompt window
2. Run the following command:

`robocopy /e f:\files\fx\water\apx\build\setup f:\files\fx\water\microsoft\apx\build\setup`

- `/e` must be used in order to include any subfolders (or empty subfolders) that exist in your source folder. Without this switch, Robocopy will only copy *files* and will ignore subfolders. It's usually best to include it.
- there is no need to add `"."` as Robocopy copies all files by default, so that would be redundant.

**Update:**

The OP has updated his question to include a requirement for source path folder wildcarding.

Source path folder wildcarding isn't supported in Robocopy, as the only wildcards it supports are those used either in file names or file extensions.

As a result of this limitation, Robocopy cannot help the OP here. An answer using an alternative scripting solution is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot but is there a way to use wildcards for Water, APX and Build as they change in the source and target the same way. So I need them to be * in the source and the target.

Comment: Can you clarify what the paths would be for one of the other examples? For example water? Is the source path: `f:\files\fx\water`? What about the destination path?

Comment: Hi I actually updated the question. But basically anything under FX, i.e. water, APX and Build can change, but whatever the change i.e. Fire/BPX/Generic will be the same in destrination, just that the destination always have MICROSOFT right under FX/FOLDER/MICROSOFT

Comment: It's a bit more confusing now because of these changing paths. When does the path change? How often? Randomly? Will it revert to the original path later? Does the destination path change too? The hardest part of this question is just trying to understand exactly what the situation is! We need a little more information in the question in order to be able to come up with a good solution.

Comment: To explain it simpler I need this: copy F:/Files/FX/*/*/*/*/*.mp4  F:/Files/FX/*/MICROSOFT/*/*/*/*.mp4

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this : 
1) In Powershell

```
Copy-Item -Path <SourcePath> -Destination <DestinationPath> # -force if already existing at the target
```

2) With Cmd

```
Copy <SourcePath> <DestinationPath>
```

Note that the file inherits permissions from the parent folder to the target.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in **PowerShell**. But we may need some clarification.

Does this command list the files we want copied?

```
gci F:\files\Fx *.mp4 -recurse | select fullname
```

If not, you need to provide the detail that will allow us to select the desired files.

Once you have that right, you construct your new path:

```
gci F:\files\Fx *.mp4 -recurse | Foreach{
   $folders = $_.Fullname.split('\')
   $NewPath = $Folders[0..3] + 'Microsoft' + $Folders[4..($Folders.Count-1)]
   $NewPath -join '\'
}
```

If those paths look right, add the **[Copy-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6)** cmdlet:

```
gci F:\files\Fx *.mp4 -recurse | Foreach{
   $folders = $_.Fullname.split('\')
   $NewPath = $Folders[0..3] + 'Microsoft' + $Folders[4..($Folders.Count-1)]
   $NewPath = $NewPath -join '\'
   Copy-Item $_.FullName $NewPath
}
```